# 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2

I'm trying to upload an image using Retrofit2 but I was getting the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat,
>   int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

UPDATE: I managed to fix the error but I'm not sure how I can convert the ImageView into Bitmap and compress it. I'm currently using Picasso in loading image into ImageView.

My image toString method:

```
     private String imagetoString() {
         ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
         byte[] imgByte = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
         return Base64.encodeToString(imgByte,Base64.DEFAULT);
         }
```

My API interface:

```
public interface ApiUpdateProfile {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("update_profile.php")
    Call<ProfileUpdate uploadImage(@Field("Photo_Location") String Photo_Location, @Field("Photo_Title") String Photo_Title);
}
```

My API client:

```
        public class ApiClient {

             public static final String BASE_URL = ("http://10.5.94.217/lara/");
             private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


             public static Retrofit getClient() {
                 if (retrofit==null) {
                     retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                             .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                             .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                             .build();
                 }
                 return retrofit;
             }
         }
```

My Image upload method:

```
private void uploadImage()
    {
        String Photo_Location = imagetoString();
        String Photo_Title = fullname.toString();

        ApiUpdateProfile apiUpdateProfile = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiUpdateProfile.class);
        Call<ProfileUpdate call = apiUpdateProfile.uploadImage(Photo_Title, Photo_Location);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ProfileUpdate>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ProfileUpdate call, Response<ProfileUpdate response) {
                ProfileUpdate profileUpdate = response.body();
                Toast.makeText(ProfileUpdateActivity.this, "Server response " + profileUpdate.getResponse(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ProfileUpdate call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileUpdateActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });
    }
```

My PHP file:

```
 <?php

 require "connection.php";

 if($con){  $title = $_POST['Photo_Title'];     $image =
 $_POST['Photo_Location'];

    $upload_path = "images/$title.jpg";

    $sql = "INSERT into employee_profile(Photo_Location, Photo_Title)
        values('$title', '$upload_path');";

    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql))    {       file_put_contents($upload_path,
 base64_decode($image));        echo json_encode(array('response'=>"Image
 uploaded"));       }   else{       echo json_encode(array('response'=>"Image
 upload failed."));     }

 mysqli_close($con); }   ?>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where's the `bitmap` object in your `imagetoString` coming from?

Comment: I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnmkMToNI-o&index=12&list=PLshdtb5UWjSoFPs3AakEpH1pmSrJVxJhs

Comment: It seems to work with him. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: It's a class variable of his `MainActivity` - and presumably you didn't set it (so it's still `NULL` in your case). Go back to part 5 of that series and check if you're missing something.